# semi specialization of templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class

```
template <class dataType>
class SSDFinder
{
   dataType a;
   dataType b;
public:
   void FindSSD();
};
```

the implementation is :

```
template<class dataType>
void SSDFinder<dataType>::FindSSD()
{
// some code. 
}
```

Now I need to specialize this function FindSSD depending on whether dataType has 2 element e.g. x, y or 3 element e.g. x, y, z.

There are multiple ways I could have 2 or 3 elements. When I start specializing for 3 elements, i could have cv::Point2i, cv::Point2d. cv::Point2f, cv::Vec and so on.

similarly for 3 element.

Is there a way I could club all the specific ones together such that all the dataType with 2 elements could have only 1 specialization and with 3 elements could have another specialization and thats all ??

There is no size() etc function in these dataTypes for me to find how many elements there are except trying to access them. For ex. i couldn't do dataType.type() to get the type information. Many data structures don't provide for that.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without checking for members with specific names.

Comment: even if i could override a segfault while trying to access the third element, i could write a fast function. Even that seems far fetched

Comment: in this case, you need to specialize the class, not the member function

Comment: oh the class is way to big with too many functions to specialize. but if i specialize a class, could I do a partial specialization ? how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to write a traits class and use `std::enable_if` :

```
template<typename T>
struct has_2_elements
  { static const bool value = false; };

template<>
struct has_2_elements<cv::Point2i>
  { static const bool value = true; };

template<>
struct has_2_elements<cv::Point2d>
  { static const bool value = true; };

template<class dataType, typename = typename std::enable_if<has_2_elements<dataType>::value, void>::type>
void SSDFinder<dataType>::FindSSD()
{
    // some code. 
}
```

While you would still have to tell by hand which classes "have 2 elements", it would be separated from your function, easy to extend, and reusable in another places in your code.

**NOTE:** `std::enable_if` is c++11, but you can find the equivalent in Boost.